# Qt 5.0 Build Warning

Tags: qt, gcc, fedora

I have installed Qt 5.0 (the whole SDK) on Fedora 17. I have configured the compiler (GCC) and everything seems to be working fine, except that when I press "Ctrl-R" for having a demo of my GUI coding, I get the following error :

```
make: Entering directory `/home/Nisarg/Documents/Qt Projects/untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_32bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.0.1/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.0.1/gcc/lib -o untitled main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/opt/Qt/5.0.1/gcc/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL**
make: Leaving directory `/home/Nisarg/Documents/Qt Projects/untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_32bit-Debug'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled] Error 1
04:07:17: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 GCC 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'.
```

(The error above is that a file called -lGL is not found)

How do I go about solving this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the libGL development files installed. It's been awhile since I used Fedora, but check your package manager for a package named something like `mesa-libGL-devel`.